# Best way to figure out pattern in tree structure

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

This question is extension to [Identifying preposition or conjunction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450705/identify-prepositons-and-individual-pos)

Have a look at this tree :

[image: Simple tree]

I have figured out that if parent of an IN is SBAR then it is conjunction, if it is PP then it is preposition.(I assume IN always comes to the **left** of SBAR or PP).

However, I am not able to iterate over tree in such fashion sucessfully.

I am not sure about these things :
1. Am going right way to separate conjunctions and prepositions?
2. At first glance I thought this logic was going correctly

as SBAR > IN > because  === conjunction
   PP > IN > with === preposition

But,
Have a look at this sentence

> I guess I’ll never be the same since we fell for you

[image]

So, Now I think this logic will be correct

if SBAR > iterate again ... left side child find IN then mark as conjunction.

[image]

Please guide me how can I go about it.
I dont have much knowledge about Tregex, Semregex or Tsurgeon. Will it be helpful in this scenario?
Please give some examples of how to correctly iterate over a tree .

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is probably to look at the dependency parses.

Actual prepositions will be attached to their heads with a [`case`](http://universaldependencies.github.io/docs/en/dep/case.html) relation, while subordinating conjunctions will be attached to their heads with a [`mark`](http://universaldependencies.github.io/docs/en/dep/mark.html) relation.

Comment: sad part is in is also marked as mark , which is preposition [mark(fighting-4, in-3)
advcl(engaged-2, fighting-4)
mark(attacked-7, after-5)] ... after is correct as subordinating conj...

Comment: Yes, this solution won't be correct in all cases because it depends on a correct parse tree and correct part-of-speech tags (in your example `fighting` is arguably incorrectly tagged as a verb) but this is true for all statistical natural language processing tools.